# How to synchronize Webots Time with ROS time?

Tags: ros, webots

I'm currently trying to synchronize the ROS time with Webots. What I'm expecting:

- The ROS time is fully depends on the Webots time. If the simulation starts running slowly, the ROS time should slow down as well, if I run webots in fast mode (> real-time), the ros time should run faster as well.

However, I'm currently not able to synchronize webots to achieve the above behavior. I followed the instructions mentioned [in the Webots documention](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/using-ros) and in [this thread](https://www.cyberbotics.com/forum?message=8230) of the old webots forum and set the ros_controller arguments --use_sim_time, --clock and --synchronize to be true, with no success. Both Times still run independently from each other.

I would be glad if anyone would have some feedback how one can achieve the synchronization.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you missed one step, you have to set the ROS /use_sim_time parameter  to true before starting your ROS node and the simulation so that it will use the time published by the /clock topic: 
http://wiki.ros.org/Clock#Using_Simulation_Time_from_the_.2BAC8-clock_Topic

Comment: You were totally right, just forgot to enable the synchronization also from the ROS side of things. Thanks a lot for pointing it out!